# jquery file upload plugin not working for greater than 5 mb file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have implemented jquery file upload plugin in Codeigniter, for any ext of file for my site. I have upgrade the upload files size to 50 mb. but while uploading files greater than 8 mb, it gives an error ( It works for less than 8 mb.). When I checked it, it shows that, progress bar and ajax process stop abnormally and $_FILES[] - this array is empty in php. For this I have increase the timeout for ajax. Then ajax process and progress bar process works fine but still I got $_FILES[] array empty. Anybody have solution or suggestion for this issue. I want to use this plugin only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the max upload limit in your php.ini?

Comment: have you changed the memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size settings of PHP?

Comment: You say it gives an error? What is the error message?

Comment: If it is not that what @Rooneyl has told then please check your .htaccess file, maybe it is because of the server time out!

Answer (score 0):

I think this this is because your hosting-provider has limited downloading files larger than 8 MB - this is similar to the system settings. Try to add to the .htaccess-file in the site root directorystring:
'php_value memory_limit 50M'

**Just be careful:** if your hosting provider has blocked php_value - directives, it can lead to the 500 error (then you have to ask your provider to increase the limit of uploading files)